# Getting "Object doesn't support this property or method" error in IE7 with this javascript and problems with tabs not anchoring properly

Tags: javascript

Now getting error Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; SLCC2; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)
Timestamp: Fri, 15 Jun 2012 02:20:10 UTC

Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 210
Char: 2
Code: 0
URI: http://www.seanprovost.com/frah_dev/j/s_jsInit.js

and my tabs arent anchoring right in IE7

```
$("#map").gMap({
            markers: [{ 
                latitude: 34.816117,
                longitude: -86.491022,
                html: "Flint River Animal Hospital",
                icon: { image: "i/googlePin.png", 
                      iconsize: [26, 46],
                      iconanchor: [12, 46],
                      infowindowanchor: [12, 0] },
                }],
            zoom: 14
});
```

----> $('#boaSectLeft').localScroll({
            target:'#sections'
        });

Anyone know whats going on with it?

Comment: UPDATE. Check site if you wish, works great in chrome and mozilla  http://seanprovost.com/frah_dev/newclients.php?form=3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This might be the issue](http://blog.inarow.net/post/227533978/stupid-comma).  I see you have a comma after defining your `icon` object (i.e the comma at the end of line `infowindowanchor: [12, 0] },` which  causes issues in IE.

Comment: @user1411823 Did you remove the correct one?  When I went to your sample URL, I see the error in Chrome now, and the Javascript reads 'infowindowanchor: [12, 0] }, }] zoom: 14` with the comma removed before the `zoom: 14`.  That one needs to be there, it's the comma after `[12, 0] }` that needs to be removed.

Comment: i removed correct comma now. Now im getting an error thats actually pointing to underlying prob i was trying to correct.

Comment: Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; SLCC2; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)
Timestamp: Fri, 15 Jun 2012 02:18:28 UTC


Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 210
Char: 2
Code: 0
URI: http://www.seanprovost.com/frah_dev/j/s_jsInit.js

Comment: @user1411823 I see `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'localScroll'` in my Chrome console.  Is `localScroll` a jQuery plugin that's missing from the page?

Comment: Ah, I see you've update your question to reflect that now too.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the last comma:

```
$("#map").gMap({
    markers: [{ 
        latitude: 34.816117,
        longitude: -86.491022,
        html: "Flint River Animal Hospital",
        icon: { image: "i/googlePin.png", 
            iconsize: [26, 46],
            iconanchor: [12, 46],
            infowindowanchor: [12, 0] }//Here
    }],
    zoom: 14
});
```

Because `icon` is the last property of your object.

However, it was supposed to work, at least in Chrome.